# Adding while loop to script causes errors on input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code to play Hangman (Python 3.5.2). I wan't my code to run forever, e.g with `while 1 < 2:`, but I start getting syntax errors on statements that work fine without the `while`. Here is my code:

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
  words = f.read().splitlines()
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
words2 = ''
alphabetCount = []
guesses = []
input = input('Input: ')
for x in range(0, len(words)):
  valid = True
  if len(input) == len(words[x]):
    for y in range(-1, len(input)-1):
      if input[y] != words[x][y] and input[y] != '_':
        valid = False
    if valid:
      words2 = words2 + (words[x])
for x in range(0, 26):
  alphabetCount.append(0)
for x in range(0, len(words2)):
  alphabetCount[alphabet.index(words2[x])] = alphabetCount[alphabet.index(words2[x])] + 1
for z in range(0, 26):
  if max(alphabetCount) != 0 and (alphabet[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))]) not in input:
    guesses.append(alphabet[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))])
  alphabetCount[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))] = 0
print (guesses)
```

Essentially, I want to loop it like this:

```
while 1 < 2:
  with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
  alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  words2 = ''
  alphabetCount = []
  guesses = []
  input = input('Input: ')
  for x in range(0, len(words)):
    valid = True
    if len(input) == len(words[x]):
      for y in range(-1, len(input)-1):
        if input[y] != words[x][y] and input[y] != '_':
          valid = False
      if valid:
        words2 = words2 + (words[x])
  for x in range(0, 26):
    alphabetCount.append(0)
  for x in range(0, len(words2)):
    alphabetCount[alphabet.index(words2[x])] = alphabetCount[alphabet.index(words2[x])] + 1
  for z in range(0, 26):
    if max(alphabetCount) != 0 and (alphabet[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))]) not in input:
      guesses.append(alphabet[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))])
    alphabetCount[alphabetCount.index(max(alphabetCount))] = 0
  print (guesses)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. No syntax errors.

Comment: Have you verified you didn't mix tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you mask the built-in function **[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)** with the assignment:

```
input = input('Input: ')
```

For one iteration, this will work just fine because you're not calling `input()` again. Doing it more than once though will use a value of `input` that is masked, in your case with a value of type `str`; calling a `str` value will result in a `TypeError`.

Change the name to something different, like:

```
my_input = input('Input: ')
```

for the error to leave, make sure you change it throughout your code.

Remember to never mix user defined names with [built-in function names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) because you'll get weird behavior.